# Load .whl packages and dependencies dynamically from python executable during runtime

Tags: python, plugins, dependencies, pyinstaller, python-wheel

I am quite new on python environment and on pyinstaller, but I really need your help.

## Context

I have a python app which loads plugins within code. Indeed, we provide new features for our users in the form of plugins, and we want them to be able to install and use those that interest them. We don't want to build a new executable file every new plugin.

We bundled our app in a executable with pyinstaller, a one folder, because it seems easier to add plugins.
`pyinstaller --clean --paths=lib/python3.8/site-packages src/main.py`

My plugins have sometimes external dependencies (lib, etc.), so foreach plugin here is my setup.py (with requirements, values from requirements.txt file) :

`setup(name='package_name',version='0.0.1',include_package_data=True,install_requires=requirements,extras_require={'all': requirements})`

## My issue

I know how to import installed modules dynamically to my code:

`module=__import__(module_name,globals(),locals(),[name],0)`

This part works.

But I have difficulties to install completely and dynamically those plugins within my code.

The solution must work on a linux ans Windows machine.

## What I tried

Let's imagine I want to import my test.whl plugin, which has a dependency with 'test2' package

1. Install the plugin with pip:
   `subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "--upgrade", package, "-t", my_one_folder_location])`
   Pro: if python and pip are installed on the Host machine it works
   Cons : You need to have python and "pip" (not "pip3" etc) on the user computer and the path. You have to be careful to have the same python version than on the package, etc. Not a recommanded solution...

I also tried to use the python installed in the pyinstaller folder but did not succeed.

2. Import every plugins in a specific directory:

> PyInstaller understands the “egg” distribution format often used for Python packages. If your script imports a module from an “egg”, PyInstaller adds the egg and its dependencies to the set of needed files.

I tried to put my .wheel packages in a folder "egg". Then my program detect the plugin, but it doesn't import my lib dependencies
`__main__:Unexpected error: no module named 'test2'`

I'm going around in circles and can't find any solutions: What is the best way to import my external .whl packages and all it's dependencies in a pyinstaller solution?